# Assembly problem adding unknown value into A

Tags: assembly, reverse-engineering, 8085

Hello i have the following program in assembly language for an 8085 microproccesor and i need to find the final value of B. Even tho the exercise is quite simple making the hexadecimal numbers into binary and then doing the logical thingies I am struggling at the line ADD B which make me add B to A which i dont know what number it is. Therefore i cant follow up with the rest of the program.Thanks in advance.

My final objective is to Calculate the final value of B without actually running the program.(i want to do it on paper)

```
MOV A,B
ADI 111
ANI FAH

XRI 11110000B
ADD B
MVI D,10
INR D
MOV C,D
ADD C
ORI ADH
SUI 11
MOV B,A
HLT
```

Comment: Your code starts with a `MOV A,B` so if you know the incoming A, you also know B.

Comment: @PeterCordes i was not given any of that.